# Conditional rewrite in .htaccess for url-shortener

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, google-url-shortener

I'm using goo.gl to shorten urls. I want to redirect to a goo.gl/xXxX if any characters trail the root domain request otherwise redirect to root domain. nyti.ms does this exactly the way I'm trying to. What does their `.htaccess` file look like?

nyti.ms/xXxX goes to nytimes.com/2014/02/26/opinion/some-article

nyti.ms/ goes to nytimes.com

I have 50% working...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://goo.gl/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code ? It should do the trick. Redirection is not working for trailing path or for root ?

Comment: Yep looks right to me too!

Comment: the code above always redirects to goo.gl. I want the code to redirect to a different site when there is no url-shorten hash appended. For example, nyti.ms/ should go to www.nytimes.com, all other urls with /xXxX should redirect to goo.gl.